# How can I combine results from multiple columns in 1 row? (Google Spreadsheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an ever expanding list of names that register for events. They register for multiple events at different occasions, causing their name to enter the list multiple times, but with different events selected.

[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44n0W.png)

The problem is that I now have to manually go through the names that have registered for an event earlier, and also manually add that event to that users first/primary entry, so that I have 1 entry per user, that includes all the events he/she has registered for.

I've tried looking for a formula that takes all the information from the current output, and cleans it up so that a) all users are deduplicated, and b) all events for that user are shown in 1 row. Please see the screen for expected output below

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHIvM.png)

Unfortunately I cannot find what I'm looking for, and I really hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
=arrayformula(let(
nameswithdupes,tocol(A2:A,1),
events,torow(C1:1,1),
matrix,not(isblank(C2:index(C2:ZZZ,counta(nameswithdupes),counta(events)))),
{{"Name",events};{unique(nameswithdupes),map(unique(nameswithdupes),lambda(eachname,if(bycol(filter(matrix,nameswithdupes=eachname),lambda(eachcol,or(eachcol))),events,)))}}))
```

We start by using LET to name arrays corresponding to the list of names (including duplicates), and the list of events. We then use the counts of these arrays to define a 2D array of TRUE/FALSE values for each each event/name instance combination. The final part is to then use MAP to filter this matrix for each unique name and OR the results BYCOL to see if each event has been signed up for by each individual name. IF transforms these TRUEs/FALSEs back into 'Event n' as per the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(range,C2:H,
     map(J2:J,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,bycol(range,lambda(Λ,iferror(+tocol(filter(Λ,A2:A=Σ),1))))))))
```

[image]

***Updated formula***:

```js
=let(name,A2:A, range,B2:H,
     map(unique(tocol(name,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,bycol(range,lambda(Λ,iferror(+tocol(filter(Λ,A2:A=Σ),1))))})))
```

Comment: Great, this seems to work! Thanks so much! Do you also have a formula to easily deduplicate the names in column J? I now did that manually, but ideally I have a formula that looks at the values from column A, and shows only the deduplicated values in column J.

Comment: Try the *Updated formula* added to the answer

Comment: I was wondering if you can help out 1 more time.. When applying the formula to our actual datasheet, I get a parsing error. I've created a new spreadsheet with the actual amount of names (>2000) and events.  My idea is that the formula doesn't work above a certain amount. It works fine up until a 1000 rows or so, but somewhere above that it goes wrong. Would you be able to have a look in this spreadsheet and advice on how to proceed? The formula should be in cell BR2. Thank you in advance